# Getting data from on-prem to Azure Synapse - "unexpected metadata of Synapse Link was detected in the source database"

Tags: azure-synapse

I'm trying to move data from table A in our on-prem database into an equivalent table A in an Azure Synapse (ASA) dedicated pool. I've set up the integration runtime, and have selected my on prem table from ASA. However, when I run a link connection I am seeing the following error:

> Failed to enable Synapse Link on the source due to 'Unexpected metadata of Synapse Link was detected in the source database.'.
> Failed to disable Synapse Link on the source due to 'Failed to drop the link topic in the source database: Failed to enable Synapse Link on the source due to 'Unexpected metadata of Synapse Link was detected in the source database.'.'.
> Continuous run ID: e52df111-9947-401e-97cb-4ef3f4532934

I'm expecting Table A in ASA to be populated with data from on-prem.

What does this mean? I'm very new to ASA so might have overlooked some setup.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the error you have got and ended up with the similar error as below:

[image]

**The main cause of error is your Azure Synapse workspace managed identity has no permissions to access the Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 storage account.**

As per Official [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/synapse-link/connect-synapse-link-sql-server-2022)

> Make sure that you've granted your Azure Synapse workspace managed identity permissions to the Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 storage account

**To grant the managed identity of Azure Synapse workspace to access the Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 storage account follow below steps:**

- Go to your Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 >> Access Control (IAM) >> Add >> Add Role assignments

[image]

- After this pick Storage Blob Data Contributor,
- For selected role choose Managed identity.
- Then under Members, choose your Azure Synapse workspace.